# Differences between C write call and Go syscall.Write

Tags: c, go, system-calls

syscall `write` returns -1 and set `errno` is a trivial case. I am interested in the status of `errno` if C `write` call returning zero or positive. The wrapper `syscall.Write` in Go simply returns `err` if `errno` is not zero for any case, which also includes the case of `write` call returns positive.

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/3cb64ea39e0d71fe2af554cbf4e99d14bc08d41b/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_386.go#L1007

However, the [man page of C `write` call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) roughly describes `errno` **may** also be set but unspecified if we write zero length buffer without explaining any detail.

Thus, the following cases seem unclear:

1. What is the status of `errno` if `write` call returning 0 for a file, a non-blocking socket, or a blocking socket?
2. When and how `write` call returning 0 and `errno` is not 0?
3. What is the status of `errno` if `write` call returning positive? Will it be negative?
4. Is there any other syscall may encounter the same situation?

I think the above description points to the difference between C `write` call and Go `syscall.Write`, which is unclear for developers, here are my thoughts:

According to the man page, returning zero is clearly defined in C `write` call for to files and for non-blocking sockets, but it's unclear whether there are non-error conditions for a blocking socket which would result in a `write()` not blocking, returning 0, and (presumably) possibly succeeding later if retried.

Indeed Go directly wraps system call `write`. However, the following code snippet seems not safe because `written` equals to zero is a case that may trigger `err` but we don't want to break the loop:

```
func writeAll(fd int, buffer []byte) bool {
    length := len(buffer)
    for length > 0 {
        written, err := syscall.Write(fd, buffer)
        if err != nil { // here
            return false
        }
        length -= written
        buffer = buffer[written:]
    }
    return true
}
```

Is there any wrong in my suspicion?

Comment: One thing to note here is that *the library functions* will never *reset/clear* `errno` - it is the caller's responsibility to do that.

Comment: @Antti: Additionally, in Go, library funtions don’t touch errno at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `write`, there are only two cases to consider:

1. If it fails, the result is -1 and `errno` is set.
2. If it succeeds, the result is 0 or larger and `errno` is not set.

There are no other cases to consider, unless you are interested in historical Unix implementations (see: [Is a return value of 0 from write(2) in C an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176443/is-a-return-value-of-0-from-write2-in-c-an-error)).

The reason that `write` may return 0 is because the input buffer may be empty.

> However, the man page of C `write` call roughly describes `errno` **may** also be set but unspecified if we write zero length buffer without explaining any detail.

All this means is that it's possible for a 0-length write to fail. If it fails, it returns -1 and sets `errno`. If it succeeds, it returns 0 and does not set `errno`. This is the same behavior for any other write, it's just mentioned in the man page because people may find it surprising that a 0-length write could fail.

> What is the status of `errno` if `write` call returning 0 for a file, a non-blocking socket, or a blocking socket?

In this case, `errno` is not set, because `write` did not fail. This will only happen if the input buffer is zero bytes.

> When and how `write` call returning 0 and `errno` is not 0?

This does not happen. Either `errno` is set and the return is -1, or `errno` is not set and the return is 0 or larger.

> What is the status of `errno` if `write` call returning positive? Will it be negative?

The `errno` value will not be set. It will have the same value as it did before the `write` call.

> Is there any other syscall may encounter the same situation?

In general, system calls will either return an error *or* they will succeed. They won't do some mixture of both. Look at the Return Value section of other man pages and you will see that they are mostly the same as `write`.

### Code

This code is safe.

```
func writeAll(fd int, buffer []byte) bool {
    length := len(buffer)
    for length > 0 {
        written, err := syscall.Write(fd, buffer)
        if err != nil { // here
            return false
        }
        length -= written
        buffer = buffer[written:]
    }
    return true
}
```

Note that it's a bit redundant, we can just do this:

```
func writeAll(fd int, buf []byte) bool {
    for len(buf) > 0 {
        n, err := syscall.Write(fd, buf)
        if err != nil {
            return false
        }
        buf = buf[n:]
    }
    return true
}
```

### A note about C

Technically, `write` is both a system call and a C function (at least on many systems). However, the C function is just a stub which invokes the system call. Go does not call this stub, it invokes the system call directly, which means that C is not involved here (well, not until you get into the kernel).

The man page shows the calling conventions and behavior of the C stub, `write`. Go chooses to copy that behavior in its own stub, `syscall.Write`. The actual system call itself only has an assembly language interface.

Comment: Thank you so much for your decent answer, it solves all my doubts regarding write call :)

Comment: Maybe a follow-up question, what if the `writeAll`'s `write` call is interrupted by CPU and another syscall get scheduled (maybe called in another goroutine) and failed, is it possible to receive the `errno` triggered from the other goroutine in the next `write` call?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Are you checking that the read is complete? Without source code there is not much for me to say.